# Socket.Close()

Tags: c#

as i understand it in C# u pass a copy of the reference by default,
no for my Example

iv'e got 2 Forms witch in the first a Socket connects and then is being passed in the constractor to the other form

now as i understand it they both have a reference to the same place in memory ,
now in the second form i call Socket.Close() 
when the second form closes , the first form is up

and the socket witch is used there was of course set to close, i want to detect that status of the socket 
something like if(Socket.Closed)

this is because in some situations i Call Socket.Disconnect(true) , and when errors occur i call Socket.Close()

my questions are :
1) how to detect if a socket is closed and not disconnected on The side it was closed on,
   (please try to understand that i could well of said a oledb connection,the socket is not 
    the issue as much as detecting if a closeable object was closed)
2) can the reference of the Socket object be set to null , then the other Socket would also reference null and that i could detect

Comment: The socket _is_ the issue beacuse different classes have different IsClosed/IsOpen/... definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect the `Socket.Connected` property.

And to avoid problems, don't even attempt to re-use a Socket object.

Comment: i didn't understand how the Socket.Connected property works 
it says in the documentation that it shows the connected state according to the last I/O operation , iv'e noticed that it dosen't always reflect on a connected socket,but i didn't really understand 
why ....

also why would we avoid reuse of the socket , to my understanding 
it is wast full to create sockets and dispose sockets.